# Contravariance in Generics C#

Tags: c#, generics, contravariance, variance

I don't know who resolve this segment code with variance:

I have an abstract father class:

```
public abstract class PdfObject
{...}
```

And two child classes:

```
public class PdfText : PdfObject
{...}

public class PdfImage : PdfObject
{...}
```

Now, my wrong or empiric code is the next:

```
public IList<PdfText> GetTexts()
{
       List<PdfText> result = new List<PdfText>();
       List<PdfObject> list = GetList();
       foreach(var item in list)
       {
           if(item is PdfText) result.Add(item)
       }
       return result;
} 

public List<PdfObject> GetList()
{...}
```

Well, i read a lot of this theme, but don't stand how use variance in generics or use a better solution for this issue.

Please, help me and thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do that isn't working or that you need help on?

Comment: Your code is fine, what's your real problem?

Comment: This cannot work with variance because IList is invariant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't have much to do with variance, directly.  Your problem is here:

```
public IList<PdfText> GetTexts()
{
    List<PdfText> result = new List<PdfText>();
    List<PdfObject> list = GetList();
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        if(item is PdfText) result.Add(item)
    }
    return result;
}
```

The static type of the `item` variable is `PdfObject` so you cannot add it to `result`; you need to cast it.  For example

```
if (item is PdfText) result.Add((PdfText)item);
```

This is inefficient because you check the type twice: once for the `is` operator and once for the cast.  Instead, you're supposed to do this:

```
public IList<PdfText> GetTexts()
{
    List<PdfText> result = new List<PdfText>();
    List<PdfObject> list = GetList();
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        var textItem = item as PdfText
        if (textItem != null) result.Add(textItem)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or, you can use linq:

```
var result = GetList().OfType<PdfText>().ToList();
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I stand corrected.  Just ran a test and it did indeed come back as null.  I will modify my incorrect statement.

Comment: @Scottie unless you can demonstrate otherwise, the `as` keyword *attempts* to cast to the type on the right, and if it cannot, returns a `null` value. You should not get a runtime exception here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this...

```
public IList<PdfText> GetTexts()
{
    List<PdfText> result = GetList()
        .Where(x => x is PdfText)
        .Select(x => (PdfText)x)
        .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Edited: This works, but OfType is better.

Comment: You could use [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) instead.

Comment: @phoog: Much better implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it off the top of my head.  Edited with a version that works.  But I still think the OfType is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a better solution in this situation.

```
public class ClientOfPdfObject<T> where T: PdfObject
{
    public List<T> GetItems()
    {
        List<PdfObject> list = GetList();
        var result = new List<T>();
        foreach (var pdfObject in list)
        {
            if (typeof (T) == pdfObject.GetType())
                result.Add((T) pdfObject);
        }
        return result;
    }

    //Get PdfObjects somewhere (ex. Db)
    private List<PdfObject> GetList()
    {
        var list = new List<PdfObject>
        {
            new PdfImage(),
            new PdfImage(),
            new PdfImage(),
            new PdfText(),
            new PdfText(),
            new PdfText(),
            new PdfText()
        };

        return list;
    }
}


static void main()
{
        var text = new ClientOfPdfObject<PdfText>();
        //contains 4 itmes (PdfText)
        var pdfTexts = text.GetItems();

        var image = new ClientOfPdfObject<PdfImage>();
        //contains 3 items (PdfImage)
        var pdfImages = image.GetItems();
}
```

Tomorrow, when you add more pdf objects (ex. PdfGraph), you don't need to change anything.